# How to include and excute another pkg file with my pkg installer, build with electron-builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder, pkg-config, pkg-resources

i have a Mac desktop app which should be installed and communicates with an external tool(installed via dmg). Now i created a dmg installer which copies both dmgs into applications. fine.
But with a new feature the external tool needs some scripts running around the install process, thats why i get it as an pkg installer.
I got the info, that i should switch to the pkg format when i want to include another pkg installer in my installer.
But when i create a pkg installer OR a dmg installer, the pkg file is not included in my installer. The size of the installer is the same with and without the extra installer file.

snippet of my old electron-builder config.yaml file looks like this(both dmg, both are copied correctly):

```
mac:
 target:
   - dmg
 dmg:
   sign: false
   writeUpdateInfo: false
 asarUnpack: 
   - tool.dmg
```

new fileformat with pkg installer

```
mac:
 target:
   - pkg
 dmg:
   sign: false
   writeUpdateInfo: false
 asarUnpack: 
   - file.pkg
```

the build.js file has this snippet
copy(
`${ __dirname }/build/file.pkg`,
`${ __dirname }/file.pkg`
);

What am i doing wrong? How can i include and execute a pkg installer inside of my own install process?

Thx for your help!